# How can I make a VisualStudio ApplicationSetting's default value be conditional?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a C# application in Visual Studio 2010 that uses several application settings. For one of these, I want its default value to be conditional, depending on whether the C# application is running as 32-bit or 64-bit. That way, if the user manually assigns the setting a value, it'll be persisted, but otherwise we choose an appropriate value on the user's behalf.

It's clear that I can set a value of the setting's type in the Value data grid cell. But is there a way to use a conditional so the default value is chosen based on specific logic?

Comment: You could check to see if a value is set, and if not, conditionally pull from one of two default values (`default_32` and `default_64`). Might not be pretty, but should work if there's no built-in support.

Comment: My specific problem was that the setting had an Enum type so I had to set a default value; null wasn't an option. To workaround it, I changed the setting type to a string so its default could be null. Then, when loading the settings, I check if the setting is null and, if so, set it appropriately. However, it'd be ideal if I didn't need this extra logic.